# Why was the AT-AT walker on Endor not used in the battle of Endor?

Tags: star-wars

Why was the AT-AT walker in *Return Of The Jedi* not used in the Battle of Endor?

Was there a Canon reason or just an out of universe reason?

Or was the walker actually in the battle and just not shown on camera?

[image: AT-AT walker on Endor]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not canon, but I have a feeling AT-ATs aren't exactly well adapted to maneuvering through the forest.

[Battle of Endor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Endor) Wiki states (uncited) that the AT-AT was used to transport surrendered Luke Skywalker to the shuttle to be taken to Death Star. NOT exactly the best choice for a taxi, but when Lord Vader says "jump"...

Also, Wiki adds:

> Meanwhile, Renegade Squadron heard over their comlinks that Solo was surrounded, and they rushed to his rescue. First, they liberated an Ewok village captured by Stormtroopers. Finally, Renegade Squadron prevented the repairs on an AT-AT that had been crippled by Solo's strike team earlier from being finished (*src: Star Wars Battlefront: Renegade Squadron*)

Comment: You could probably show that AT-ATs were infeasible by comparing their heights (something like 50-75 ft) to the average height of the trees in the area where the Battle of Endor was filmed (since they're redwood trees, probably over 50ft at least) - if the trees are taller than the AT-AT's shoulders, there's not much advantage to using them since all they'll see is greenery. I would, but I can't google it atm :(

Comment: I definitely remember scenes in the EU where AT-AT had to stay behind and/or clear the way with their weapons in a dense forest. So I think this answer is valid; this big guns would have remained at the base to protect it.

Comment: AT = All terrain... I guess not!

Comment: @Jared An ATAT is seen in a trailer for _Star Wars BattleFront_ - https://youtu.be/ZwWLns7-xN8?t=57s

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer**: Endor is not an open area as the planet is on forest setting, whereas Hoth has an open space which the AT-AT can move freely. Additionally, the AT-AT walkers were too huge in size to be in implementation in the fores.

Answer (score -3):

The AT-AT was used as a patrol on Endor.That's  what I read and it would be hard to control even if its "ALL TERRAIN" because the dead trees on the ground and bushes and other things.Also since the AT-ATs neck is the most weak part,all the branches from the trees (witch are taller then the AT-AT) would tear it apart.Besides the ewoks have those log traps. AT-ST's heads are about as high as the knee part of the AT-AT so the logs would cripple the legs instead of tangling them like in "The Empire Strikes Back".

Comment: "That's what I read"? Where?